# Get REST caller IPAddress via Aspect

Tags: rest, aop, aspectj

Is it possible to get the IP Address of a REST service's caller via an Aspect?  If so, how can it be done?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. How can it be done? Easily.

Comment: Great non-answer ... thanks.

Comment: You did not even get the irony. My answer was exactly like your great non-question. I thought that someone with 450 points would figure it out and know how to ask a question in a smart enough way for it to be answered. Did you really expect that anyone can say anything intelligent about such a question?!? Show me the code, dude!